# Using CSS, can Google Chrome create an alpha channels effect similar to a 24 bit PNG?

Tags: css, google-chrome, png-24

You can make some cool tricks using a 24 bit PNG, which has a gradient from opaque to completely transparent. Elements sliding beneath this PNG will appear to *disappear whilst fading*.

Is this possible using CSS only with Google Chrome? I only have to target this browser.

I'd like to avoid a slice of 1px tall elements with varying `opacity` set.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can, just use a `-webkit-gradient` with Alpha values as the background image:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, rgba(255,255,255,1)),color-stop(1, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
```

And if you are just targeting Chrome, you can also use `:before` and `:after` to add the gradients if you wanted to. Here is a quick example. You can view [it live on CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com/uSyqe) *(This method works in a lot more than Chrome, but breaks in FF 3.0 and just doesn't work in a number of IE versions)* :

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}


div:before {
  top: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, rgba(255,255,255,1)),color-stop(1, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
}


div:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(1, rgba(255,255,255,1)),color-stop(0, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
}
```

Comment: All I knew were WebKit supported gradients, and rgba supported alpha, and you married these ideas perfectly! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad I could help. I guess you figured it out `rgba(0,0,0,1)` would be solid black, and `rgb(0,0,0,0)` would be fully transparent.